# Oculus VRC with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm developping a game with Unity.
I'm trying to check all of the VRC (Virtual Reality Check) tests, especially TestResponseToRecenterRequest and TestAppShouldQuit ( [link](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-vrcvalidator/) ).
My problem is, I have absolutly no idea how to listen these requests.
Most of forums said to use ovr_GetSessionStatus. However, it's a C++ method, not a C# one. Can you point me to a valid solution to listen ovr status or, at least, handle recenter and quit requests ?

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already fixed this, but i found that the ovr_GetSessionStatus is exposed as static variables on the OVRPlugin class, so you can check on an Update().

```
if (OVRPlugin.shouldRecenter)
{
  OVRManager.display.RecenterPose();
}
```